# When S3 bucket policy is set in AWS website, should I do it again in my Javacode that will be running in an Ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have set S3 bucket policy in my S3 account via web browser

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sppyr.png

My issue is, the java code of my web app when run in my local laptop, it uploads image to S3.

```
final AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(
                  new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey*",
                      "secretKey")));
              s3.setRegion(Region.US_West.toAWSRegion());
              s3.setEndpoint("s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com");
versionId = s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("bucketName", name, convFile)).getVersionId();
```

But when I deploy my web app to Elastic Beanstalk, it doesn't successfully upload images to S3 object. 
So Should I programmatically code S3 bucket policy again in my Java Code?

PS: Additional details that may be useful : [Why am I able to upload to AWS S3 from my localhost, but not from my AWS Elastic BeanStalk instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46970918/why-am-i-able-to-upload-to-aws-s3-from-my-localhost-but-not-from-my-aws-elastic?noredirect=1#comment80892842_46970918)

Answer (score 1):

Your S3 bucket policy is too permissive. You should delete it asap.

Instead of explicitly supply credentials to your Elastic Beanstalk app in code, you should create an IAM role that the Elastic Beanstalk app will assume. That IAM role should have an attached IAM policy that allows *appropriate* access to your S3 bucket, and to the objects in the bucket.

When testing on your laptop, your app does not need to have credentials in the code. Instead, your app should leverage the fact that the AWS SDK will retrieve credentials for you from the environment that the app is running in. You should use the [default credential provider chain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm reading those documentation now.I'm kinda struck in this doc. What is the key that they refer to as mentioned in this doc      S3Object s3object = s3Client.getObject(
          new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-roles.html

Comment: You can read about keys here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-keys.

Comment: Ok, Stepping back for a second,
"Instead, your......is running in." - 

1) So for both running webapp in my laptop and running webapp in AWS Ec2, we should "Use the default credential provider chain (recommended)."

2) I created an role and created access policy and assigned it to my Ec2 instance. Now I'm struck which of these methodologies I should use a) DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain 
b) InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider
3) There is no accessKey & secKey for roles?
4) How can I have consistency in using AWS credentials between my laptop and while running in Ec2?

Please help.

Comment: Use IAM user credentials when running on your laptop and use an IAM role when running in Elastic Beanstalk. Two different sets of credentials, but give them both the necessary S3 permissions. I recommend reading the various AWS guides/videos  on how to use IAM.